# Number of relations from $A$ to $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two sets $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{5,6,7,8,9\}$.

What is the number of relations from $A$ to $B$ which 1 is not in their domain?

So what I thought about doing is this
The number of relation, I think is $5^4$, right?
I'll just subtract the number of relations from $\{1\}$ to $B$, which suppose to be $5^1$.
Is that correct?

As a side question, I believe I have a lot more relations from $\{1\}$ to $B$ than $5$, right? is $|B|^{|A|}$ the right formula here?

Thanks

Comment: Relations are just subsets of $A\times B$, so the total number of them is $2^{5\cdot 4}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That should be an answer.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think of the other question? number of relations without 1 in the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any two sets $C$ to $D$, the relations from $C$ to $D$ are precisely the subsets of $C\times D$, of which there are $2^{|C|\times|D|}$ (which is what [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781726/number-of-relations-from-a-to-b#comment1621042_781726) refers to).

However, the question is actually "relations without $1$ in their domain". The simplest way I can think to answer that is: drop $1$ from the domain, and count the number of relations from that. To wit: take $C=A\setminus \{1\}$, $D=B$, then $2^{|C|\times|D|}=2^{16}$.

Another way is to count the relations with $1$ in the domain and subtract that from the total number of relations. It will be more complicated (not hard, just more lengthy) in this case, though, so I'll skip the details.

As for $|B|^{|A|}$, that gives you the number of *functions* from $A$ to $B$ (where for every element in $A$ you choose one and only one element in $B$).