# Number of relations from A to B with specific domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have two sets $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $B = \{5,6,7,8,9\}$

I need to find the number of relations from $A$ to $B$ which includes $\{1,2,3\}$ in the domain.
It says to use the Inclusion–exclusion principle.

So what I thought about doing is this
I'll mark $A_1$ as the relations from $\{1\}$ to $B$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ accordingly.
I believe I need to find ($A_1$ And $A_2$ And $A_3$) (Right?).
I can find the sum of $|A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3|$ and also the sum of $2$ groups combinations.
The question is, can I find ($A_1$ or $A_2$ or $A_3$)? If I can, I'll just subtract those and find what I need, right?

Hopefully it is clear what I've wrote.
Thanks

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781726/number-of-relations-from-a-to-b

Comment: I know, I asked this related question, this is a different one. didn't want to add it to the old question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Each relation consists of a domain and a range, right?

There are $2$ optional domains:

- $\{1,2,3\}$
- $\{1,2,3,4\}$

And there is $1$ optional range:

- $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$

We create a relation by taking a valid domain and a valid range, and mapping **each** element in the domain to **one** element in the range:

- We can create $5^3$ different relations between $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$
- We can create $5^4$ different relations between $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$

So in total, we can create $5^3+5^4=750$ different relations.

Comment: I believe you are talking about functions, not relations. from {1,2,3} to {5,6,7,8,9} we have 2^(3*5) relations and so on. please correct me if I'm mistaken. Thanks

Comment: @user2102697: I was indeed talking about functions, but I figured that they were the same as relations (or at least that they were OP's intention in the first place). If otherwise, then obviously this answer is not entirely relevant to the question, but perhaps it can be used in order to conclude the exact answer... Thanks.